# How to count the length of the first segment in an IP address using a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is as follows (but it does not work):

```
IP_address = "216.3.122.18"  
seg_1_len = 0  

for char in IP_address:  
        while char != ".":  
            seg_1_len += 1  
            print(seg_1_len)  
        if char == '.':  
            break
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] - what precisely does *"does not work"* mean? One obvious problem - you have a while loop which contains nothing that changes the value of its condition, so it will either never start or never end.

Comment: Why using a `while` loop? `len(IP_address.split('.')[0])` will do the job.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you running a while loop inside a for loop. `char` variable is already storing each character of the IP address in every iteration. So just check if char is `.`, then stop otherwise increment `seg_1_len` by `1` in every iteration. If you use a while loop like you have, it will go to **`infinite loop`** in the first iteration itself. Think about it!!

Try this :

```
IP_address = "216.3.122.18"  
seg_1_len = 0  

for char in IP_address:  
    if char == '.':  
        break  
    else:
        seg_1_len+=1
print seg_1_len
```

Output:

```
3
```

As per your question if you still want to use `while` loop, then do this :

```
IP_address = "216.3.122.18"  
seg_1_len = 0

i=0
while IP_address[i] != ".":  
    seg_1_len += 1  
    i+=1
print(seg_1_len)
```

**Or if you want something `pythonic`** :D

```
print len(IP_address.split(".")[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looping through the ip address with the for loop and then constantly querying the first character with the while loop, if `while` is changed to `if` then your code works.

```
IP_address = "216.3.122.18"  
seg_1_len = 0  

for char in IP_address:
    if char != ".":  
        seg_1_len += 1  
    else:  
        break
print(seg_1_len)
```

Answer (score -1):

In a for-loop used to find something, you would normally use the else like this (contrived) example:

```
def seg1len(ipaddy):
    seg1 = ""
    for char in ipaddy:  
        if char == '.':   # test for equality to the break condition..
            break         # .. and break at the top of the for loop
        seg1 += char      # do the for-loop work (you don't need an else clause to the if)
    else:                 # the else would go with the for and would be executed whenever the for loop ran without hitting break
        raise ValueError("ipaddy contains no dots")
    return len(seg1)
```

again, this was a contrived example. You should use one of (fastest):

```
IP_address = "216.3.122.18"  
seg_1_len = IP_address.find('.')  # returns -1 if there is no '.'
```

or

```
seg_1_len = IP_address.index('.')  # raises a ValueError if there i sno '.'
```

or

```
len(ipaddy.split('.')[0])
```

a solution using while could be as simple as:

```
seg_1_length = 1
while IP_address[seg_1_length] != '.':
    seg_1_length += 1
```

assuming we know that the input is a valid ip4 address (it must contain at least one `'.'` and can't start with a `'.'`).

If you can't assume that the input is valid you'll need to code more defensively, e.g.:

```
i = 0
while i < len(ipaddy) and ipaddy[i] != '.':
    i += 1
assert i > 0, "ip address can't start with a dot"
assert i <= 3, "the first octet can't be more than 3 characters long"
seg_1_length = i
```

Answer (score -1):

**There are several ways.**

This method is the easiest to understand:

```
IP_address = "216.3.122.18"

i = 0
while i <= len(IP_address) - 1 and IP_address[i] != ".":
    i += 1

seg_1_len = i
```

You can also do:

```
seg_1_len = len(IP_address.split(".")[0])
```

Comment: that's not python

Comment: @thebjorn Yes it is!

Comment: Thanks for editing. You can also get rid of the awkward `- 1` by using `<` rather than `<=`.